# Send Message to WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, websocket

I want to send a message to a WebSocket.
I already figured out, that you need to send some kind of a header, with the type of message, the length, the keys, and then at last the text.
So I tried this:

```
byte type = (byte) 0b10000001;
byte zero = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { type, 0, zero, zero, zero, zero, 79, 75};
bytes[1] = (byte) (bytes.length - 6);
sendBytes(bytes);
```

I used this website to know what bytes to send: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java

My sendBytes function looks like this:

```
public void sendBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        out.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where out is an OutputStream.

I also found some things out: When I send type as 0b10000011, the website knows that the Opcode is 3. When I change it back to 1 again, it gives me the following Error: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0
That would mean, the type is send now somehow starts with this: 0b1100xxxx
I confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should be using `byte` not `char`. `char` is 2 byte long in Java. See also the exact example you've linked to, which uses `byte`.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right I totally forgot that char has 2 bytes, I will try it out soon

Comment: I changed it to bytes, but it didn't fix the error

Comment: @I think you should update your question to reflect what your current code looks like. Also maybe look at the wire using tools like Wireshark to see what actually gets transferred and if this matches your expectations.

Comment: I changed it now, I will try out wireshark, but I never used it before

Comment: Doesn't have the `String` the same problem as the `char` you've used before, i.e. 2 bytes per character?

Comment: I played around for a bit, but it still doesn't work. I updated the code accordingly